# AssertJ asserting that List<Long> contains only long[]

Tags: java, junit, assertj

Is there a way to assert that a List contains only/exactly long[] array?

Code:

```
 // arrange
    long[] result = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // act
    List<Long> digitPowNumbers = SumDigPower.findDigitPowNumbers(1, 6);

    // assert
    assertThat(digitPowNumbers).containsExactly(result);
}
```

I'm getting `Cannot resolve method containsExactly(long[])`. How can I do this assertion? Is there a way without just typing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` into `containsExactly` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`containsExactly()` expects an array of the same element type as your list, which is `Long`, not the primitive `long`. Change your array type and it should work:

```
Long[] result = {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};
```

Comment: Im getting incompatible types (required Long Found int) in the array. Do I have to add L to the integers for it to work?

Comment: It's the only way? I have quite a lot of arrays and it's going to be very tiresome to add Ls everywhere

Comment: @doublemc You can also write a custom matcher.

Comment: @doublemc If you're using Guava, you can do `List<Long> result = Longs.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);` and compare them using `equals()`. With Apache Commons, you can do `Long[] result = Array.toObject(new long[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});`. Otherwise I don't have any simple workaround.

Comment: With Java8 you can convert your `long` `array` into a `List<Long>` via `Arrays.stream(result).mapToObj(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());` without using any extra library.

Comment: You can likely use some regex to replace `number,` by `numberL,`.